# How to programatically scroll CollectionView after its rendering

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to programatically scroll CollectionView after its rendering however, I can't seem to find the lifecycle hook to call the scroll function in.

Calling the scroll function in OnAppearing hook is out of the question because that hook exists only in ContentPage and my CollectionView exists in a LazyView that gets initialized after clicking a button on a page.

```
private void ScrollToItemAtPosition(int idx) {
        PhotoCollection.ScrollTo(idx, position: ScrollToPosition.Center);
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Will need your LazyView code to be added to better understand your problem and give you a valid advice

Comment: First, calling in `OnAppearing` is "too early". So even if you did want to do it there, it wouldn't do you any good. Second, there are no cross-platform life-cycle hooks for views (only for pages). Its a fair bit of custom coding per-platform to make the hook you want; `mvvmcross` does include it in their view/viewmodel paradigm - `MvxViewModel` has an overridable `ViewAppeared` method. But that requires committing to their viewmodel-centric navigation paradigm. A major architectural change. You could look at source in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross to see how they make `ViewAppeared`.